# MongoDb multi document operation with a single document lock

Tags: node.js, mongodb

For example< we have a next db structure:

- Users
- Items
- Games

Items belongs to Users (userId field in item) aka inventory. 
Users can create games. 
Users can join created games. Only two users allowed to join a game.
When game is completed, all items from users inventories should be transferred to "winner" inventory.

I want to build a flow, by using NodeJs, to handle "joinGame", "winGame" cases.
In a MySql database i used transactions to lock "game" record and perform all operations in a single transaction to ensure data consistency.

I have no idea how to make it in mongo in a correct way.
Digging on internet, i found two solution:

1. Write a worker, what cycles through a "game" records to finalize them.
2. Use app-level (node executable) lock
3. ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In general the concept is "don't join" and put all the "related" data into a single document. This is how you live without transactions. It's not a relational database, so if you are just going to try doing things the same way, then there's little point in using a different storage engine in the first place.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39210371/2313887

Comment: Thank you very much. I have another q: for example i want to transfer inventory items from one document to another using query like sql “where findinset(item.id, ids)”. Is there a way in mongo to do it in a single atomic operation? Or it would be two: remove, add?